# How detect the files that JavaFx Media player will fail to play

Tags: java, javafx, javasound, aiff

I've built a small library of files to analyse JavaFx capabilities at playing them.

There are some file types for which JavaFx does only raise an asynchronous error at the level of the media player.

Is it possible to detect that before playing the file or in some synchronous way ? In order for example, to prevent the user from playing it, or to switch to an alternate playing method.

This is about the "media player error - level 2" error in the code below.
And this appends with some .AIFF file types (e.g. Signed 16 bits PCM, ...)

This is the code:

```
try {
    String fileStr = file.toURI().toURL().toExternalForm();
    Media media = new Media(fileStr);
    if (media.getError() == null) {
        media.setOnError(() -> {
            System.err.println("media error - level 2");
        });
        MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(media);
        if (player.getError() == null) {

            player.setOnError(() -> {
                System.err.println("media player error - level 2");
            });
            player.statusProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<MediaPlayer.Status>() {
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends MediaPlayer.Status> obs,
                                    MediaPlayer.Status oldStatus, MediaPlayer.Status newStatus) {
                    appendLog("JavaFx :: Status :: " + Objects.toString(oldStatus, "--")
                            + " -> " + Objects.toString(newStatus, "--"));
                }
            });

            player.setOnEndOfMedia(() -> {
                appendLog("JavaFx :: reached the end");
                player.stop();
            });

            appendLog("JavaFx :: Start");
            player.play();
            success = true;
            appendLog("JavaFx :: Started");
        }
        else {
            throw new InternalException("media player error - level 1");
        }
    }
    else {
        throw new InternalException("media error - level 1");
    }
} catch (InternalException| MediaException ex) {
    txtFile.append("JavaFx :: " + ex.getMessage() + "\n");
    success = false;
} catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
    txtFile.append("JavaFx :: " + ex.getMessage() + "\n");
    return;
}
```

I'm running with JavaSE8.

Comment: wondering why synchronous vs. asynchronous makes a difference?

Comment: If synchronous, then I could have in my player class a method such as ```boolean isFilePlayable(file file);``` and in my (Swing) GUI class, a ```playButton.setEnabled(player.isFilePlayable(file));``` (actually my player class has no access to the GUI. I'm using JavaFx only here for its beter aptitude at media playing than the traditional JavaSound libraries)

Comment: you still can do so: even if not possible to be certain up front if a file is playable, you can disable after the first failing trial ..

Comment: This is how I do. But I'd prefer to disable the Play button pro-actively instead of reactively. But that's not a big issue. I've bigger ones... Thanks anyway.